# Sets of functions closed within composition.

Tags: functions

I want to know all sets of single-variate functions that fulfill the following qualities:

$\forall_{f:R^2 \to R^2} \forall_{g \in CAF} \forall_{h \in CAF} \exists_{k\in CAF} k(x) = f(g(x),h(x))$ where CAF is the set I am wishing to find.

I know that the set of constants and the set of piece wise constants each satisfy that equation. Do any others?

Comment: Is f fixed in advance?

Comment: @symplectomorphic No, that property is *not* satisfied by the class of polynomials: e.g. take $g, h$ to be polynomials and $f(x, y)=e^x$. (That said, I also can't understand at all the connection to antidifferentiation.)

Comment: What does "CAF" stand for?

Comment: What is a "closed-algebraic function"?

Comment: @Noah: yes, whoops; I misread and thought $f$ was constrained to lie in the set, too. Still I find the rest of the post hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete description of all families of functions with the property you describe.

For a unary function $g$, say the *discernment* of $g$ is the equivalence relation $a\sim_g b\iff g(a)=g(b)$. Then a family $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies your property when and only when we have:

> For all $g, h\in \mathcal{S}$ and all unary $j$, if $\sim_j\supseteq(\sim_g\cap \sim_h)$ then $j\in \mathcal{S}$.

That is, if [$g(a)=g(b)$ and $h(a)=h(b)$] implies $j(a)=j(b)$, then $j\in\mathcal{S}$.

---

Here's why:

Suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a family of functions satisfying the property I wrote above, and let $g, h\in\mathcal{S}$ and $f$ be any binary function, and let $u=f\circ (g, h)$. Then we have $$g(x)=g(y)\mbox{ and }h(x)=h(y)\implies u(x)=f(g(x), h(x))=f(g(y), h(y))=u(y).$$ So $\sim_u\supseteq (\sim_g\cap \sim_h)$, and so $u\in\mathcal{S}$. So $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies your property.

Now suppose $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies your property, $g, h\in\mathcal{S}$, and $u$ is some unary function such that $\sim_u\supseteq(\sim_g\cap \sim_h)$. Let $f(x, y)=u(z)$ if for some $z$ we have $x=g(z), y=h(z)$, and $f(x, y)=0$ otherwise (this case doesn't matter). Note that $f$ is indeed well-defined: although there could be distinct $z_1, z_2$ satisfying $x=g(z_i), y=h(z_i)$, by assumption on $u$ we'd have $u(z_1)=u(z_2)$. It's now easy to show that $f\circ (g, h)=u$, and so $u\in\mathcal{S}$.

---

You ask about specific examples; the characterization above lets you cook up examples easily.

For example, fix some equivalence relation $\approx$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe $\approx$ is "differs by an integer multiple of $2\pi$". Then the family of functions $\mathcal{S}_\approx$ which are "$\approx$-periodic" - in the sense that $g(x)=g(y)$ whenever $x\approx y$ - satisfies your property.

We can also start with two equivalence relations, or three, or infinitely many - we just have to take their *finite intersections*. For example, the class of functions which are *periodic with some rational period* satisfies your property. However, the class of periodic functions does *not* - take a function $g$ of period $1$ and a function $h$ of period $\pi$. Then $\sim_g\cap \sim_h$ is just "$=$," and so any class of functions containing both $g$ and $h$ must in fact consist of *all* functions. Similarly, any class satisfying your property which contains *any injective functions* must consist of all functions.

In general, I can think of two kinds of natural example for this property:

- The class of all periodic functions with period in some "reasonable" set $P$ (specifically: any two elements of $P$ should be rational multiples of each other, and $P$ should be closed under integer multiplication $(x\in P\implies kx\in P$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$)).
- The class of all functions with range of cardinality $<\kappa$, for $\kappa$ an infinite cardinal or $2$. So: the class of all constant functions (range $=1$), or piecewise constant functions (range $<\omega$), or functions with countable range (range $<\omega_1$), or so on. We can also restrict these: e.g. the class of functions whose restriction to $[0, 1]$ has countable range, etc.

We can mix-and-match these - e.g. the class of functions which are periodic with rational period, *and also* take on only finitely many values when restricted to the domain $(0, 1)$. However, ultimately this strikes me as a very unnatural property, and I would be surprised if many natural examples emerged.

Comment: Or in other words, such families are in bijection with filters on the lattice of equivalence relations on your domain set.